# How to make header sticky in prestashop 1.7

Tags: html, css, header, prestashop, sticky

i need my website https://alto.7180.eu/it/ to have a sticky header.

I tried setting the position to sticky but it seems it's not enough, i think i need to have some other elements set to position relative, but i don't know which ones.

I'm using a slightly modified version of the original Classic template for prestashop 1.7.6

As of right now this is the structure of the site:

```
<body>
  <main>

    <header style="position: fixed;">
        <!--Header Code with logo, menu... -->
    </header>

   <!--Page Code-->
   </main>
</body>
```

Could you please help me? Feel free to ask anything if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index: 1` and `width: 100%` to display it.